# How do I measure the memory usage of an object in python?

Tags: python, memory-management

I have a python class `foo` that contains:

- data (ints, floats)
- lists (of ints, of floats, and of other objects)
- dictionaries (of ints, of floats, of other objects)

Assuming that there are no back-references (cycles), is there an easy way to measure the total memory usage of a `foo` object ?

Essentially, I am looking for a ***recursive version*** of `sys.getsizeof`

A few of the tools I came across included: heapy, objgraph and gc, but I don't think any of them are up to the task (I may be corrected on this)

Comment: What is your end goal for this? Would a generic code profiler be enough?

Comment: My python code is using a lot of memory. After ruling out a memory leak, I am trying to track the memory usage of the code over a few hours in order to see where the increase in memory is coming from.

Comment: Depending on your goal (as above), maybe looking at the pickled size would a good indication of memory size.

Answer (score 23):

Try [Pympler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pympler/), which describes itself as *"A development tool to measure, monitor and analyze the memory behavior of Python objects."*

Something along the lines of

```
>>> import pympler
>>> print pympler.asizeof.asizeof(your_object)
```

has been helpful to me in the past.

See [examples](https://pympler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#usage-examples) from the official documentation and [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pympler) on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to get the size of the type, or the actual complex object, but looking at getsizeof, the documentation points to this recipe for a robust recursive version:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/

so I'd assume there's no 'stock' python call that will do it, otherwise the docs would mention it.

Comment: Did you just google "Recursive version sys.getsizeof()" ? :)  I hate it when the solution is so obvious!...thanks, will try it out.

Comment: well, I played around in IDLE for like five minutes. I've never looked at memory stuff with python, so this was a cool crash course, but yeah, that's straight out of the official docs. good luck!