# Deep version of sys.getsizeof

Tags: python, memory, python-3.x, deep-copy

I want to calculate the memory used by an object. `sys.getsizeof` is great, but is shallow (for example, called on a list, it would not include the memory taken by the list's elements).

I'd like to write a generic "deep" version of `sys.getsizeof`. I understand there is some ambiguity in the definition of "deep"; I'm perfectly happy with the [definition followed by `copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html).

Here's my first attempt:

```
def get_deep_sizeof(x, level=0, processed=None):
    if processed is None:
        # we're here only if this function is called by client code, not recursively
        processed = set()
    processed.add(id(x))
    mem = sys.getsizeof(x)
    if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(x, str):
        for xx in x:
            if id(xx) in processed:
                continue
            mem += get_deep_sizeof(xx, level+1, processed)
            if isinstance(x, dict):
                mem += get_deep_sizeof(x[xx], level+1, processed)
    return mem
```

It suffers from two known problems, and an unknown number of unknown problems:

- I don't know how to traverse a generic container in a way that captures all the linked objects. Therefore, I iterated using `in`, and hard coded the case of dictionary (to include values, and not just the keys). Obviously, this will not work for other classes like dictionary.
- I had to hard code the exclusion of `str` (which is an iterable, and yet does not have links to any other objects). Again, this will break if there are more objects like that.

I suspect that using `in` is not a good idea, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Ah, it's a duplicate question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022725/how-do-i-measure-the-memory-usage-of-an-object-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331471/in-memory-size-of-python-stucture.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that [Pympler](http://packages.python.org/Pympler/) has already beaten you to the punch on this one.

From their [documentation](https://pympler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#usage-examples):

```
>>> from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
>>> obj = [1, 2, (3, 4), 'text']
>>> asizeof(obj)
176
```

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/pympler/pympler/blob/master/pympler/asizeof.py).

Comment: Looks great. However, it seems there's no elegant solution to this problem; `pympler` is hard coding `dict` (and allows to register other classes to be treated as such). I wonder why iteration through all attributes (except those specially excluded) doesn't work...