# Why does numpy takes so much memory for an array of strings?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

It seems putting an array of strings into an numpy array takes over 20 times more memory than the raw array.  I could understand that it would take 10% more memory due to some overhead, but I would like to know why it takes 2000% percent more.

```
import numpy as np
from sys import getsizeof

txt = ["adsfjwofj owejifowijefiwjfoi of wofjwoijfwoijfoiwej"]
print(getsizeof(txt))

txts = [txt for _ in range(10000)]
print(getsizeof(txts))

txts_np = np.array(txts)
print(getsizeof(txts_np))
```

The output:

```
72
87624
2040112
```

I thought there was something wrong with my installation, but I tried it also on another machine with a different numpy version and got the same result.

Comment: `getsizeof` isn't recursive, list don't contain the actual objects, they contain pointers to them. A more fair comparison will be: `sum(getsizeof(x) for x in txts)`. I am not sure how `__sizeof__` works in case of nd arrays though, if it's implemented.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208410/deep-version-of-sys-getsizeof

Answer (score 0):

This is a self-answer since it was answered in the comments by @Ashwini Chaudhary.

My observation that numpy takes much more memory than a raw array is not valid. 
`sys.getsizeof` is not a good tool for reporting memory usage: it seems that it reports correctly the size of the numpy array, but only the size occupied by the pointers in the raw array.