# Google cloud functions hit 10MB rate limits while streaming data to big query regardless of the using chunks?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am testing the Google cloud functions. The objective is to stream more than 10MB to into big query table. I have divided the data into chunks then use that chunk to load data to big query. Memory allocated is 2GB. However, it does not work.

```
from bigquery_uploader.datauploader import Datauploader, bq_streaming_cloud_function_table_schema
import sys

def upload_bigquery_chunks(data_list, bigquery_extractor, bq_table_id, chunk_mb=4):
    def getChunks(data_list, n=20):
        for i in range(0, len(data_list), n):
            yield data_list[i: i + n]

    avg_size_dd = sys.getsizeof(data_list) / len(data_list)
    num_chunks = int(chunk_mb * (10 ** 6) / avg_size_dd)
    data_chunks = getChunks(data_list, num_chunks)
    for data in data_chunks:
        print(sys.getsizeof(data))
        bigquery_extractor.client.insert_rows_json(bq_table_id, data)



def bq_data_uploader_stream(request):
    bq_project_id = 'my_project_id'
    bq_dataset = 'my_dataset'
    bq_table_id = "bq_streaming_cloud_function_table"

    data_list = list()
    # 1MB = 1 * (10**6)
    MBs = 10
    while sys.getsizeof(data_list) < MBs * (10 ** 6):
        data_list.append({'campaign_name': 'Google Cloud Function', 'campaign_id': 123456789})

    bq_extractor = Datauploader(bq_project_id)
    bq_extractor.create_table(bq_dataset, bq_table_id, bq_streaming_cloud_function_table_schema)
    bq_table_id = '{0}.{1}.{2}'.format(bq_project_id, bq_dataset, bq_table_id)
    upload_bigquery_chunks(data_list, bq_extractor, bq_table_id)
```

I get the following Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 346, in run_http_function
    result = _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 217, in invoke_user_function
    return call_user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 210, in call_user_function
    return self._user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 34, in bq_data_uploader_stream
    upload_bigquery_chunks(data_list, bq_extractor, bq_table_id)
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 16, in upload_bigquery_chunks
    bigquery_extractor.client.insert_rows_json(bq_table_id, data)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 2269, in insert_rows_json
    retry, method="POST", path="%s/insertAll" % table.path, data=data
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 476, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 277, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 182, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 393, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my_project_id/datasets/my_dataset/tables/bq_streaming_cloud_function_table/insertAll: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is within your code.
Referring to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python#comment51968201_450034) `sys.getsizeof()` doesn't work for nested objects, e.g. list of dicts. That's why in fact your `data_list` object is much bigger than 10 MBs. I would suggest using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14208608/12232507) workaround to determine size of a complex object. Though keep in mind that it might be slow due to its recursive nature. I would also recommend rewriting your while loop or it will get really slow with a lot of small dictionaries being added to a list.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [Bigquery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts) there is a limit of 10 MB per HTTP request. If you divide the data in chunks of 4mb and still send more than 10mb or 3 chunks in your case you will still hit this limit.

Try to either limit the stream or as a possible workaround you can try to upload the data to Cloud Storage in one chunk and then perform the import from the bucket directly.

Comment: `bigquery_extractor.client.insert_rows_json(bq_table_id, data)`  doesn't this imply that i am making different http request each of which is less than 10MB?