# Why is the memory usage of a Python list smaller than expected?

Tags: python, list, memory

[image]

As seen in the picture. 50 000 000 records only take 404M memory, why? Since one record takes 83 Bytes, 50 000 000 records should take 3967M memory.

```py
>>> import sys
>>> a=[]
>>> for it in range(5*10**7):a.append("miJ8ZNFG9iFqiQQohvyTWwqsij2rJCiZ7v"+str(it))
... 
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(a)/1024**2)
404.4306411743164
>>> print(sys.getsizeof("miJ8ZNFG9iFqiQQohvyTWwqsij2rJCiZ7v"))
83
>>> print(83*5*10**7/1024**2)
3957.7484130859375
>>>
```

Comment: Someone else had a similar query as you did but went a bit further, so this is more of a related thread: [Deep version of sys.getsizeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208410/deep-version-of-sys-getsizeof)

Answer (score 5):

`sys.getsizeof` only reports the cost of the `list` itself, not its contents. So you're seeing the cost of storing the `list` object header, plus (a little over) 50M pointers; you're likely on a 64 bit (eight byte) pointer system, thus storage for 50M pointers is ~400 MB. Getting the true size would require `sys.getsizeof` to be called for each object, each object's `__dict__` (if applicable), etc., recursively, and it won't be 100% accurate since some of the objects (e.g. small `int`s) are likely shared; [this is not a rabbit hole you want to go down](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5022725/364696).

Comment: yes. 64bit. I care about the actual storage(obtain  list contents). so it mean if a list that have  50 000 000 records. actually all related storage is  3957  + 404 M?

Comment: @purplecity: Well, your records are 83 bytes, plus the length of the stringified `int` you're adding on, so a bit larger than that, more like 4339 + 404 M, but yes, that's roughly correct.