# Keras: How to get model predictions( or last layer output) in a custom generator during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have made a custom generator in which I need my model's prediction, during training, to do some calculations on it, before it is trained against the true labels. Therefore, I save the model first and then call `model.predict()` on the current state.

```
from keras.models import load_model
def custom_generator(model):
  while True:
    state, target_labels = next(train_it)

    model.save('my_model.h5')
    #pause training and do some calculations on the output of the model trained so far     
    print(state)
    print(target_labels)
    model.predict(state)         
    #resume training
    #model = load_model('my_model.h5')

    yield state, target_labels

model3.fit_generator(custom_generator(model3), steps_per_epoch=1, epochs = 10)
loss = model3.evaluate_generator(test_it, steps=1)
loss
```

I get the following error due to calling `model.predict(model)` in the `custom_generator()`

Error:

> ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_2/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 200),
>   dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

Kindly, help me how to get model predictions(or last layer output) in a custom generator during training.

This is my model:

```
#libraries
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
print(model.summary())

#add layers
z = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu')(model.output)
z = Conv2D(1,(1,1), activation='relu')(z)
z = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(z)
predictions3 = Dense(200, activation='softmax')(z)
model3 = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=predictions3)
for layer in model3.layers[:20]:
   layer.trainable = False
for layer in model3.layers[20:]:
   layer.trainable = True
model3.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

Image data generators for loading training and testing data

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
# create a data generator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
# load and iterate training dataset
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('DATA/C_Train/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=1)
test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('DATA/C_Test/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=1)
```

Comment: could you please provide `train_it` and `test_it`?

Comment: sure those are just image data generators, used to load training and testing data

Comment: When you load a model, the saved model doesn't get fully deleted from the running kernel - this can be troublesome; try deleting the saved model before loading and after predicting - or do: predict -> save -> del -> load -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58137677/keras-model-training-memory-leak/58138230#58138230)

Comment: Try insert `model._make_predict_function()` after you load the model (see [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6462)).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon predicting directly from a model that is currently being trained doesn't work...

Comment: @GaryGoh that doesn't work either. It throws "Tensor Tensor("dense_6/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 200), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph." error

Comment: @UmairJavaid Do you depend on the functionality of `fit_generator` somehow (e.g. multiprocessing)? What you seek can be easily accomplished via `train_on_batch` and data fed in a for/while-loop

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Can u show/give me an example please

Comment: @UmairJavaid It'd look something like [this](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw#example) (see "for epoch in range..."); if you're fine with it, I can write a complete answer

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Wouldn't it be very slow?

Comment: @UmairJavaid Unless your `fit_generator` sets `use_multiprocessing=True`, it'll be just as fast, if not faster -- I train all my models via `train_on_batch` as it gives me greater control and minimizes redundant processes used by `fit` and `fit_generator`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200370/discussion-between-umair-javaid-and-overlordgolddragon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet may be to write a custom train loop via `train_on_batch` or `fit`; the former's only disadvantaged  if `use_multiprocessing=True`, or using callbacks - which isn't the case. Below is an implementation with `train_on_batch` - *if* you use `fit` instead (for multiprocessing, callbacks, etc), make sure you feed only *one* batch at a time, and provide *no* validation data (use `model.evaluate` instead) - else the control flow breaks. (Also, a custom `Callback` is a valid, but involved alternative)

---

**CUSTOM TRAIN LOOP**

```py
iters_per_epoch = len(train_it) // batch_size
num_epochs = 5
outs_store_freq = 20 # in iters
print_loss_freq = 20 # in iters

iter_num = 0
epoch_num = 0
model_outputs = []
loss_history  = []

while epoch_num < num_epochs:
    while iter_num < iters_per_epoch:
        x_train, y_train = next(train_it)
        loss_history += [model3.train_on_batch(x_train, y_train)]

        x_test, y_test = next(test_it)
        if iter_num % outs_store_freq == 0:
            model_outputs += [model3.predict(x_test)]
        if iter_num % print_loss_freq == 0:
            print("Iter {} loss: {}".format(iter_num, loss_history[-1]))

        iter_num += 1
    print("EPOCH {} FINISHED".format(epoch_num + 1))
    epoch_num += 1
    iter_num = 0 # reset counter
```

---

**FULL CODE**

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
print(model.summary())

#add layers
z = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu')(model.output)
z = Conv2D(1,(1,1), activation='relu')(z)
z = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(z)
predictions3 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(z)
model3 = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=predictions3)

for layer in model3.layers[:20]:
   layer.trainable = False
for layer in model3.layers[20:]:
   layer.trainable = True

model3.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), 
               loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

```
batch_size = 1
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('DATA/C_Train/', 
                                        class_mode='categorical', 
                                        batch_size=batch_size)
test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('DATA/C_Test/', 
                                      class_mode='categorical', 
                                      batch_size=batch_size)
```

*[custom train loop here]*

---

**BONUS CODE**: to get outputs of *any* layer, use below:

```
def get_layer_outputs(model, layer_name, input_data, learning_phase=1):
    outputs   = [layer.output for layer in model.layers if layer_name in layer.name]
    layers_fn = K.function([model.input, K.learning_phase()], outputs)
    return [layers_fn([input_data,learning_phase])][0]

outs = get_layer_outputs(model, 'dense_1', x_test, 0) # 0 == inference mode
```