# Keras, how to see what's happening between layers and iterations

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm training a simple CNN on the MNIST dataset. This is form a tutorial (https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-convolutional-neural-network-from-scratch-for-mnist-handwritten-digit-classification/).

```
def define_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    # compile model
    opt = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I actually want to be able to step through the training process. So starting with an example from the dataset:

[image: one example from MNIST dataset]

I want to see the 32 initialised kernels and the resulting output of the convolutions. Then maybe I want to see these things again a bunch of iterations later when the model has started to converge. I want to then be able to see the outputs of MaxPooling, Flatten, and the Dense layers.

So my question is not around how to visualise things (I'll use `print` and `pypolot.imshow` for that), but more about how I can code it up so that I can look into all of these things wherever I want.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193588/keras-how-to-get-model-predictions-or-last-layer-output-in-a-custom-generator) may be of help (scroll for custom train loop); also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193588/keras-how-to-get-model-predictions-or-last-layer-output-in-a-custom-generator)

Comment: You can use `model.layers` to iterate over all the layers of the model and then feed the images to see the output at each layer, after the training has completed.