# tf.keras OOM even on a small LSTM model with a batch size of 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I've encountered this error while migrating to TensorFlow 2.0 from TensorFlow 1.5. I would like to specifically state that this model **runs correctly on 1.5**. The only thing that is changed is migration from generator (BTW, batch size was 8) to *tf.Dataset* while feeding *.fit()*.

I've looked into a lot of threads on Stack Overflow regarding OOM issues on GPU, however, most of them were about the problems with the really huge tensors, while mine is a small [256,128] or with big batch sizes.

Here is my model:

```
def build_model(self):
    self.g_Model = Sequential()
    self.g_Model.add(Embedding(input_dim=self.g_Max_features, output_dim=256, name='X'))
    self.g_Model.add(LSTM(128))
    self.g_Model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    self.g_Model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    self.g_Model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
X (Embedding)                (None, None, 256)         256000    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 128)               197120    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 453,249
Trainable params: 453,249
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Here is my train function:

```
def train_model(self):
    if self.g_Model is None:
        self.build_model()

    dataset = self.prepare_the_data()
    self.g_Model.fit(dataset, epochs=2)
```

And the preparation of the data itself:

```
@staticmethod
def prepare_the_data():
    lstm_feature_description = {
        'X_input': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(CONFIG.g_keras_lstm_max_document_length, tf.float32),
        'y': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
    }

    def _parse_lstm_function(example_proto):
        # Parse the input tf.Example proto using the dictionary above.
        parsed = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized=example_proto, features=lstm_feature_description)
        return parsed["X_input"], parsed["y"]

    # Start Preparing The Data
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(CONFIG.g_record_file_lstm)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=5000)
    dataset = dataset.map(map_func=_parse_lstm_function)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=1)

    for next_element in dataset:
        tf.print(next_element)

    return dataset
```

Dataset contains 40 elements. Here is how one of them looks like:

```
([[0 0 0 ... 1 10 3]], [0])
```

*X_input* is a *tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor* of 24000 size and *y* is of the same type, but size is 1 (just a label).

So, when running .fit() I receive the following OOM error (part 1):

```
2019-11-02 18:42:52.426444: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:419] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 128.0KiB (rounded to 131072).  Current allocation summary follows.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.428463: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 2753, Chunks in use: 2753. 688.3KiB allocated for chunks. 688.3KiB in use in bin. 10.8KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.428723: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 78217, Chunks in use: 78217. 38.19MiB allocated for chunks. 38.19MiB in use in bin. 38.19MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.428982: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (1024):  Total Chunks: 24001, Chunks in use: 24001. 23.44MiB allocated for chunks. 23.44MiB in use in bin. 23.44MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.429247: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (2048):  Total Chunks: 3, Chunks in use: 3. 6.0KiB allocated for chunks. 6.0KiB in use in bin. 6.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.429481: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (4096):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.429704: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (8192):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.429920: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (16384):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.430138: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (32768):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.430359: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (65536):     Total Chunks: 10892, Chunks in use: 10892. 680.75MiB allocated for chunks. 680.75MiB in use in bin. 680.75MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.430613: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (131072):    Total Chunks: 10894, Chunks in use: 10894. 1.33GiB allocated for chunks. 1.33GiB in use in bin. 1.33GiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.430855: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (262144):    Total Chunks: 3, Chunks in use: 3. 1022.8KiB allocated for chunks. 1022.8KiB in use in bin. 768.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.431091: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (524288):    Total Chunks: 3, Chunks in use: 3. 2.00MiB allocated for chunks. 2.00MiB in use in bin. 1.50MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.431323: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (1048576):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.431539: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (2097152):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.431755: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (4194304):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.431970: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (8388608):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.432193: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (16777216):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.432419: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (33554432):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.442986: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (67108864):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.443324: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (134217728):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.443543: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (268435456):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-02 18:42:52.443767: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:885] Bin for 128.0KiB was 128.0KiB, Chunk State: 
2019-11-02 18:42:52.443895: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:898] Next region of size 1048576
2019-11-02 18:42:52.444010: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000703600000 next 1 of size 1280
2019-11-02 18:42:52.444139: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000703600500 next 9 of size 256
2019-11-02 18:42:52.444267: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000703600600 next 13 of size 256
...
```

Part 2:

```
2019-11-02 18:44:43.211483: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 1 Chunks of size 525056 totalling 512.8KiB
2019-11-02 18:44:43.211607: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 1 Chunks of size 1047808 totalling 1023.3KiB
2019-11-02 18:44:43.211731: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:921] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 2.06GiB
2019-11-02 18:44:43.211851: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:923] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 2210712576 memory_limit_: 2210712780 available bytes: 204 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 4294967296
2019-11-02 18:44:43.212060: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:929] Stats: 
Limit:                  2210712780
InUse:                  2210712576
MaxInUse:               2210712576
NumAllocs:                  137751
MaxAllocSize:             33554432

2019-11-02 18:44:43.216115: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:424] ****************************************************************************************************
2019-11-02 18:44:43.216331: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at split_op.cc:311 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[256,128] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
2019-11-02 18:44:43.216642: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[256,128] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node sequential/lstm/while/body/_1/split}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[Reshape_12/_28]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

2019-11-02 18:44:43.223629: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[256,128] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node sequential/lstm/while/body/_1/split}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

What I've tried already with no luck:

1. I've set set_memory_growth=True
2. Moved all the code from the train function, except building the
   model and .fit() itself
3. Lowered batch size to 1.

I really don't understand what is going on as my model is pretty small and batch size is just 1. I'm using GTX1060 3GB. So, any help is VERY appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58575279/does-model-fit-upload-the-whole-training-dataset-to-the-gpu/58575326?noredirect=1#comment103480065_58575326); also ensure your CUDA & cuDNN are installed properly & versions compatible w/ TF 2.0.0. As a temporary workaround, try `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`

Comment: I've tried tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution(). Same error in my case unfortunately. Regarding CUDA and cuDNN versions: I'm using CUDA 10.0.130 and cuDNN 7.6.4.38. If it makes any difference I've also installed TensorRT 6.0.1.5.

Comment: The CUDA/cuDNN suggestion isn't a trivial one; it decides _a lot_. Which versions are you running, and how did you install them (via package manager or built from source)?

Comment: I've listed the versions above in the edit. I'm running Win10, so I've installed them using NVIDIA installer (CUDA) and cuDNN is copied from the archive provided by NVIDIA manually.

Comment: Good; were you able to [verify installations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.0/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#verify-installation), and build CUDA samples solutions (not all but most of them)? Also some official steps listed will throw errors, but are "OK" to ignore. The entire process was a mess for me, but as a last step Anaconda installed cudatoolkit again to its environment to make it work - I may write a step-by-step on this, but until then, something's surely not right with your case, and CUDA installs may be a culprit.

Comment: I've compiled some samples and yes, they are working. At least deviceQuery and bandwidthTest. The only thing that slightly bothering me is this line: CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version 10.1 / 10.0. It means that I have CUDA driver which is newer than Runtime version. However, according to some documentation, it just shouldn't be the other way around. Results of this test are PASSED as well.

Comment: You seem to have followed the steps correctly as far as I can tell; I recommend opening a TensorFlow Git issue on this. If you haven't already, try [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/), and install [`tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu) _before_ `tensorflow` (latter may not be needed at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't believe how stupid my mistake was. I was able to recognize it only by luck after different Q&As posted by @OverLordGoldDragon.

During the import phase I've utilized the following statements:

```
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, Embedding
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.preprocessing import sequence
```

Instead, I should've used these:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence
```

BTW, latest PyCharm Professional does not provide auto-completion for tf.keras statements, which turned me down in the first place. By surprise, tf.python.keras auto-completetion works correctly.

More info could be found here: [Issues with tf.python.keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279628/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-keras-and-tf-python-keras/58279629#58279629)

Comment: Oh boy. I should've recalled to ask just in case - yeah, `tf.python`'s full of fireworks. If the problem's now resolved, consider upvoting the linked issue's answer. -- (P.S., how did you even come across that Q&A? I didn't even mention it here)