# Difference between using import keras and import tensorflow.keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've been using tensorflow for cpu on my laptop and due to it been so slow I decided to move to my desktop pc and use tensorflow for gpu.

The problem is that in my desktop computer I can't import like this, which I'm able to do on my laptop:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
```

So I decided to use the keras module with tensorflow-gpu as backend, so my imports on desktop look like this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.applications import MobileNetV2
```

Also, my conda list on laptop looks like this:

```
keras                     2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
tensorboard               2.1.0                     py3_0
tensorflow                2.1.0           eigen_py36hdbbabfe_0
tensorflow-base           2.1.0           eigen_py36h49b2757_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0              pyhd54b08b_0
```

And my conda list on desktop looks like this:

```
keras                     2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
tensorboard               2.1.0                     py3_0
tensorflow                2.1.0           gpu_py36h3346743_0
tensorflow-base           2.1.0           gpu_py36h55f5790_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0              pyhd54b08b_0
tensorflow-gpu            2.1.0                h0d30ee6_0
```

So, what's the difference between using the imports like tensorflow.keras.applications and using directly keras.applications and which one is better or worse? I looked everywhere and I couldn't find a solution for the imports on my desktop, which I'd like to fix because I like using imports like tensorflow.keras.

Answer (score 6):

`tensorflow.keras` imports use [TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r2.0) repository code, whereas `keras` imports use [Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras) repository code. The two use independent method/class implementations, even if `keras` imports from `tensorflow`.

Depending on your use, functionality may differ significantly, or not much. `tensorflow.keras` is recommended per being better maintaned and more up-to-date - *unless* you use TF <2, where the two are on par for most part, except with [performance considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441514/why-is-tensorflow-2-much-slower-than-tensorflow-1#answer-58653632).

Comment: Thanks for the information! Do you know by chance any way of fixing my imports on desktop? Using tensorflow.keras seems to be the best option and when I try to do tensorflow.keras on desktop it just doesn't work and I can't find a solution anywhere

Comment: @IgnacioFrizzera Why doesn't it work? Include any error you see in your question.

Comment: I fixed the imports thing, it was a bug from PyCharm. Had to update to the latest version and it fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is not much of a difference now. Keras is inside TensorFlow now because google choose to maintain it to complement TensorFlow because Keras is a high-level API. I suggest using tensorflow.keras because in the future it will have more support because of the google team.

[reference](https://www.fast.ai/2017/01/03/keras/)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, (1) `keras` module is in a different development path from `tensorflow.Keras`. You can check it by install the latest version of both and run this terminal command:

```
> pip list | grep -i keras
Keras                2.3.1       
Keras-Applications   1.0.8       
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0
```

compare with

```
> python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.keras.__version__)"
2.2.4-tf

> pip list | grep tensorflow                        
tensorflow           2.1.0
```

(2) From my experiences, `tensorflow.keras` has fewer flexibility to access certain modules. For example, let's say we want to create custom convolution/pooling layer by modifying `compute_output_shape()`. Then we've to import it by `from keras.utils.conv_utils import conv_output_length`. But I've not found a way at this time to import `conv_output_length()` in Tensorflow v2.x.

But, going forward, `tensorflow.keras` will get more better support from Google. Look at this graph
[Keras contrib graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAHra.png)
compare with
[Tensorflow contrib graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxjLD.png)

Comment: Note that since this answer the import strategy of tf has changed, and it uses the keras version if installed.