# How to correctly utilise GPU power?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Short version: Tensorflow Keras model is training much slower on Tesla T4 than on GTX 970 (both are working, checked with `nvidia-smi`).

Long version: I have two host machines. One is PC with GTX 970 with `Tensorflow 2.1.0`, the other is GCP AI Platform Notebook with Tesla T4 with `Tensorflow 2.3.0`. I am running the same code on both of them, all training data is stored in RAM as numpy arrays, `dtype` is the same ('float16'), `batch_size` is also the same (8, GTX wouldn't work with anything above that, but I have also tried 64 on Tesla, didn't make any difference). Why is Tesla, with twice computing power of GTX, working about 2.5 times slower? How can I use my GPU correctly to train my models faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for a fair comparison, you have to use the same exact version of TensorFlow, since there have been reports of performance differences in the TensorFlow versions [Why is TensorFlow 2 much slower than TensorFlow 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441514/why-is-tensorflow-2-much-slower-than-tensorflow-1). Note that the post contains comparisons also between TF 2.1 vs TF 2.2 vs TF 2.3

The post above also has recommendations on how to prepare + fit for a good performance.

Second of all, it may be the case that the CPU preprocessing is slower on a machine as compared to another one, hence another possible source of difference.