# Tensorflow ahead-of-time compilation without eager mode?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Hi I'm using the tensorflow [ahead-of-time compilation(AOT)](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/tfcompile) to compile tensorflow graph to self-contained binary. After switching from tf v1.14 to v2.2, the running time of the compiled binary increase by more than twice. Is this expected? If so, is there optimizations that I can do? If the AOT is by default using eager execution, is there a way to disable it, as [this post](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33487) mentions that disabling eager execution would make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Tensorflow 2.3` has addressed many of the performance issues, you should be able to find the better performance by upgrading to `Tensorflow 2.3`.

Disabling the eager execution is not the ideal way in TF2, instead you can use `tf.function` for performance optimized graphs.

You can follow this post for more details and benchmark on TF1 vs TF2 in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441514/why-is-tensorflow-2-much-slower-than-tensorflow-1).