# How do you prevent memory usage to explode when using Keras in a loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

My problem seems to be very common.

I am doing some reinforcement learning using a vanilla policy gradient method. The environment is just a simple one period game where the state and action spaces are the real line. The agent is a neural network with two output heads that I build manually using dense layers from Keras, e.g. my first hidden layer would be

```
layers.Dense(NH[0], activation ="relu", \
             kernel_initializer=initializers.GlorotNormal())(inputs)
```

where NH contains a list of number of neurons for hidden layers. The outputs are the mean and standard deviation for my gaussian policy. I don't if this part matters, but I included it nonetheless.

The environment is simple: the state is a normal variable, the action is some real scalar, and there is just one period. I run the policy a bunch of times, collect the resulting batch and use the tools from tf.GradientTape() to update the network on the basis of a custom loss function. I have no problem running that code thousands of times to see the algorithm learn.

The real problem is that I'd like to run the learning process multiple times, each time re-initializing the network weights randomly to have distributions for the history of rewards, but if I run all of this in a loop the computer freezes rapidly. Apparently, this is a very common problem with Keras and Tensorflow, one that people have been complaining about for years and it is still a problem... Now, I have tried the usual solutions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58137677/keras-model-training-memory-leak), people suggested adding something like the following at the end of the loop so that before I reinitialize the network I get a clean slate.

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
gc.collect()
del actor
```

This doesn't solve the problem. Then, I saw someone gave a function that went a little further

```
def reset_keras(model):

# Clear model, if possible
try:
    del model
except:
    pass

# Garbage collection
gc.collect()

# Clear and close tensorflow session
session = K.get_session() # Get session
K.clear_session()         # Clear session
session.close()           # Close session

# Reset all tensorflow graphs
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
```

And that doesn't work either. I also tried moving around the order of the first three commands and it doesn't work either...

Anyone has any idea how to solve the problem? It would also be useful to know **why** this happens. I'd also like to know how to profile memory usage here so that I don't have to wait 4 hours to learn the computer is freezing again with the new solution.

In fact, if you have a minimal working example where you can demonstrate the code doesn't lead to exploding memory use, I would be very much disposed to re-code the whole damn thing from scratch to stop the problem. As a side note, why haven't the developers solve this issue? It's the only package on both R and Python where this has ever happened to me...

EDIT
As asked, I provide a minimal working example of the issue. I made up a quick game: it's a moving target where the optimal action is to play some multiple of the state value which yields a reward of 0.

I wrote down an actor class and used a simple linear regression as a critic which may be turned off. If you look at the memory usage, it is climbing... That game won't crash my computer unless I play it a lot more, but it shows that memory usage increases.

```
import numpy      as np
import psutil

import tensorflow                    as tf
import tensorflow.keras              as keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers       as layers
import tensorflow.keras.initializers as initializers

import tensorflow.python.keras.backend as kb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

BATCH    = 10
MC_DRAWS = 2000
M        = 10

# Training options
LR = 0.01
def display_memory():
    print( f'{round(psutil.virtual_memory().used/2**30, 2)} GB' )

class Actor:

    def __init__(self):
        self.nn    = self.make_actor()
        self.batch = BATCH
        self.opt   = keras.optimizers.Adam( learning_rate = LR )

    def make_actor(self):
        inputs = layers.Input( shape=(1) )
        hidden = layers.Dense(5, activation='relu', 
                              kernel_initializer=initializers.GlorotNormal() )(inputs)
        mu     = layers.Dense(1, activation='linear',
                          kernel_initializer=initializers.GlorotNormal() )(hidden)
        sigma  = layers.Dense(1, activation='softplus',
                          kernel_initializer=initializers.GlorotNormal() )(hidden)
    
        nn  = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[mu, sigma])
    
        return nn

    def update_weights(self, state, action, reward):

        # Get proper format
        state  = tf.constant(state,  dtype='float32', shape=(self.batch,1))
        action = tf.constant(action, dtype='float32', shape=(self.batch,1))
        reward = tf.constant(reward, dtype='float32', shape=(self.batch,1))
    
        # Update Policy Network Parameters
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:   
            # Compute Gaussian loss
            loss_value = self.custom_loss(state, action, reward)
            loss_value = tf.math.reduce_mean( loss_value, keepdims=True )
        
            # Compute gradients
            grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, self.nn.trainable_variables)
 
            # Apply gradients to update network weights
            self.opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.nn.trainable_variables))
        
    def custom_loss(self, state, action, reward):
        # Obtain mean and standard deviation
        nn_mu, nn_sigma = self.nn(state)
    
        # Gaussian pdf
        pdf_value = tf.exp(-0.5 *((action - nn_mu) / (nn_sigma))**2) *\
                    1/(nn_sigma*tf.sqrt(2 *np.pi))
                    
        # Log probabilities
        log_prob  = tf.math.log( pdf_value + 1e-5 )
    
        # Compute loss
        loss_actor = -reward * log_prob
    
        return loss_actor

class moving_target_game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.action_range = [-np.inf, np.inf]
        self.state_range  = [1, 2]
        self.reward_range = [-np.inf, 0]

    def draw(self):
        return np.random.ranint(low  = self.state_range[0],
                            high = self.state_range[1])

    def get_reward(self, action, state):
        return -(5*state - action)**2

class Critic:  
    def __init__(self):
    
        self.order      = 3
        self.projection = None

    def predict(self, state, reward):
    
        # Enforce proper format
        x = np.array( state ).reshape(-1,1)
        y = np.array( reward ).reshape(-1,1)
    
        # Make regression matrix
        X = np.ones( shape = x.shape )
        for i in range( self.order ):
            X = np.hstack( (X, x**(i+1)) )
        
        # Prediction
        xt = x.transpose()
        P  = x @ np.linalg.inv( xt @ x  ) @ xt
        Py = P @ y
    
        self.projection = P
    
        return Py

#%% Moving Target Game with Actor and Actor-Critic

do_actor_critic = True

display_memory()

history    = np.zeros( shape=(MC_DRAWS, M) )
env        = moving_target_game()

for m in range(M):

    # New Actor Network
    actor  = Actor()

    if do_actor_critic:
        critic = Critic()

    for i in range(MC_DRAWS):
    
        state_tape  = []
        action_tape = []
        reward_tape = []
    
        for j in range(BATCH):
        
            # Draw state
            state = env.draw()
            s     = tf.constant([state], dtype='float32')
        
            # Take action
            mu, sigma = actor.nn( s )
            a         = tf.random.normal([1], mean=mu, stddev=sigma)
        
            # Reward
            r = env.get_reward( state, a )
        
            # Collect results
            action_tape.append( float(a)     )
            reward_tape.append( float(r)     )
            state_tape.append(  float(state) )
        
            del (s, a, mu, sigma)
    
        # Update network weights
        history[i,m] = np.mean( reward_tape )
    
        if do_actor_critic:
            # Update critic
            value = critic.predict(state_tape, reward_tape)
            # Benchmark reward
            mod = np.array(reward_tape).reshape(-1,1) - value
            # Update actor
            actor.update_weights(state_tape, action_tape, mod)
        else:
            actor.update_weights(state_tape, action_tape, reward_tape)

    del actor
    kb.clear_session()

    if do_actor_critic:
        del critic
    
    print( f'Average Reward on last: {np.mean(reward_tape)} ' )
    display_memory()

plt.plot( history )
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal working example where you can demonstrate the code does lead to exploding memory use?

Comment: @Lescruel I will post one today (at some point during the next 6 hours or so). It's simply because I didn't have time yesterday.

Comment: It might take a while... I tried with a trivial example and I can't see to replicate the problem I have with my full script.

Comment: @Lescurel I added a working example where the memory grows slowly. If I do this on larger scaler, it's going to grow fast. You can change M to see it grow faster. Hell, the first time I run the loop, I get somewhere around 2.9 GB and I quickly get close to 3.5 over multiple attempts to run it.

Comment: Perhaps you could launch a training process, and when the training is done, pipe the output and close the process entirely. This will force TF to clean itself up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try restarting the backend by calling

```
reset_tensorflow_keras_backend()
```

after each model estimation, where the function is defined like:

```
def reset_tensorflow_keras_backend():
    # to be further investigated, but this seems to be enough
    import tensorflow as tf
    import tensorflow.keras as keras
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    _ = gc.collect()
```