# Python3 numpy array size compare to list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I always thought numpy array is more compact and takes less memory size compare to list, however, for a 3-D float64 np array,

```
print (sys.getsizeof(result2)/1024./1024./1024.)
print (sys.getsizeof(result2.astype('float16'))/1024./1024./1024.)
print (sys.getsizeof(list(result2))/1024./1024./1024.)
print (sys.getsizeof(result2.tolist())/1024./1024./1024.)
```

The output is,

```
0.6521792411804199
0.16304489970207214
0.00033977627754211426
0.0003019943833351135
```

The list took much smaller memory. Is it validate to use `sys.getsizeof` for list? If it is, can I do anything to improve np array memory use?

######################

Using pympler @J_H, (it seems pympler can't deal with arraies in a list, like list(a 3-D array ). )

```
print (result2.nbytes/1024./1024./1024.)
print (asizeof.asizeof(result2)/1024./1024./1024.)
print (result2.astype('float16').nbytes/1024./1024./1024.)
print (asizeof.asizeof(list(result2))/1024./1024./1024.)
print (asizeof.asizeof(result2.tolist())/1024./1024./1024.)

0.6521791219711304
0.6521792411804199
0.1630447804927826
0.004566863179206848
4.078836984932423
```

Thank you all!

Comment: `getsizeof` is non-recursive, i.e. it will not account for the conent of a container.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022725/how-do-i-measure-the-memory-usage-of-an-object-in-python

Comment: The memory use of a ndarray` is easy - `arr.nbytes`, or product of shape and bytes per element.  Memory use of a list is hard to estimate.

Answer (score 1):

You show that each of your `list` elements consumes 8 bytes.

But each element is just a pointer to a 24-byte float object.

Additionally, when you start with a 3-D array,
you'll be looking at lists within lists.
You could recurse through the data structures yourself
to accurately add up the allocated bytes.
Or you could use [pympler](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/#usage-examples).