# Why a list of dataframes occupies less memory than the single dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I am trying to optimize the memory consumption of some data processing that I have to make on some large .csv files. I started using sys.getsizeof() to check whether it would be convenient to convert dataframes to lists or vice-versa (my data usually contains just numbers).
Then I notice this: my list of 47 Pandas Dataframes occupies just 0.00052 MB.
But the size of the single Dataframes is greater than the size of the list!
Here is the code I am using:

```
    path = 'D:\\folder_of_folders'
    os.chdir(path)
    fileList = glob.glob(path+'\\*') #Load all folders into a file list
    dfList = [] #declare an empty list
    final_df_columns = ['column_name1','column_name2']  #name of the columns to keep
    for file in fileList:
       try: 
            df = pd.read_csv(file+'\\filename.csv', usecols=final_df_columns) #read the addresses from the list into pandas dataframe
            dfList.append(df) #append the dataframes into dfList (a list of data frames)
        except FileNotFoundError : 
            print("File "+file+" not found")
    print(str(sys.getsizeof(dfList)/1000000) + ' MB')
    print(str(sys.getsizeof(dfList[0])/1000000) + ' MB')
    print(str(sys.getsizeof(dfList[1])/1000000) + ' MB')
    print(str(sys.getsizeof(dfList[46])/1000000) + ' MB')
```

and Output is:
0.00052 MB
4.349776 MB
4.356944 MB
0.313456 MB
How is this possible? Clearly the actual memory occupied by dfList is not 0.00052 MB. How do I find the correct value?
Thank you!
Ok, recursive size is what I needed, seems obvious now... For now I am using the code from here:https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/ which seems to work fine.

Comment: from the documentation `Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.` so when applied to the list, it will return the size of list itself without the contents. try [pympler.asizeof](https://pympler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/asizeof.html#pympler.asizeof.asizeof)

Answer (score 0):

`sys.getsizeof` is not deep/recursive so you only get the size of the list object not of it's contents

As answered here:
[Deep version of sys.getsizeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208410/deep-version-of-sys-getsizeof)

The https://pympler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/asizeof.html lib might help:

```py
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
#[your code here]
print(asize(dfList)/1000000 + ' MB')
```

See this answer for more options:
[How do I measure the memory usage of an object in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022725/how-do-i-measure-the-memory-usage-of-an-object-in-python)